# With React, how can I reuse the setState function instead of copying and pasting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate

I have an app I'm making. The idea is that you set the state to different things based off what you click. In this case, the state is the image src variable. I currently have this...

```
   merryWeather = () => {
      this.setState({
         imgPath: merrys
      })
   }

   maxJPegasus = () => {
      this.setState({
         imgPath: pega
      })
   }

   betterCallLamar = () => {
      this.setState({
         imgPath: lamars
      })
   }

   betterCallLester = () => {
      this.setState({
         imgPath: lesters
      })
   }
```

And some other state setting functions. How can I write these as one function, and call that same function over and over?

Comment: Just make a single function and pass the values like `merrys, pega` as arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a single function and pass the parameter to be set as `imgPath`.

```
setImgPath = (imgPath) => {
  this.setState({imgPath});
}
```

Comment: Hello, the issue now is that when I call the function with 
onClick={this.setImgPath(lamars)} it loads the image instantly, not onclick

Comment: If you can't get the values from your components to pass in, you could create new functions with the values automatically passed in using something like lodash's partial function. For example:

    onClick={partial(this.setImgPath, merrys)}

Comment: @Matiny Although thats a good sign that you need to break these down into their own components, and pass setImgPath and imageUrl in as props

Comment: @Matiny if you want to pass parameters on click you should do `onClick={() => this.setImagePath(lamars)}` parenthesis means execution in javascript, you need to pass function as parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an `updateState` function that accepts a `name` and `value` or a function that updates `imgPath` for you.

```
updateState = (name, value) => {
    this.setState({
        [name]: value
    });
}
merryWeahter = () => {
    this.updateState('imgPath', merrys);
}
maxJPegasus = () => {
    this.updateState('imgPath', pega);
}
```

OR

```
updateImgPath = value => {
    this.setState({
        imgPath: value
    });
}
merryWeahter = () => {
    this.updateImgPath(merrys);
}
maxJPegasus = () => {
    this.updateImgPath(pega);
}
```

Comment: Hello, I'm having the same issue as the above responder. When I set it that way, the image loads instantly, not onClick. By default, I'm calling the functions with no parentheses so at present I'm not getting instant loading.

Comment: @Matiny You can use `.bind()` to pass params to a function. `onClick={this.updateImgPath.bind(this, merrys)`